# Javascript regex - split string with regular expression

Tags: javascript, split-function

I need to style my JavaScript number string so would it be possible I can convert/split string and assign style . I tried split but need to know correct regular expression.

Example:

input: `22222`

output: `<p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
'22222'.split('').map(function(x) {
    return '<p>'+x+'</p>';
}).join('');
```

**Output**: `<p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p>`

Comment: Thanks, Could you please explain what is x argument in this function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: also map() function does not support by IE8 ?